# SQL order by column name

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have some data from excel exported to a MySql server. I want to do a query with results sorted with column names as in excel.

I had this query statement:

```
SELECT CellValue, Col, Row FROM cell WHERE Col != "A" ORDER BY Col ASC;
```

But the result is order in a way, not what I expected.

```
AA, AB, AC, B, BA, C, CA, CB, ...
```

What I want is

```
B, C, AA, AB, ...
```

What should I change/add to the query statement to have my wanted results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a two-tier sort, first by the length of `col`, followed by the value of `col`:

```sql
SELECT CellValue, Col, `Row`
FROM cell
WHERE Col != 'A'
ORDER BY LENGTH(Col), Col;
```

Note that `ROW` became a reserved MySQL keyword as of MySQL 8+.  You should avoid using this as a name for your columns (or tables).

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL you can sort by length of value first, like this:

```
with test as (
select 'AA' as id
union select 'AC'
union select 'B'
union select 'BA'
union select 'AAA'
union select 'ABC'
union select 'C'
union select 'CA'
union select 'CB'
union select 'DDDD')
select *
from test
order by char_length(test.id), test.id
```

[image]